# Non-user controlled TextareaAutosize and TextField goes into infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How does one supposed to use controlled [react-textarea-autosize](https://mui.com/base/react-textarea-autosize/) with non-user input? Example:

```
import TextareaAutosize from '@mui/base/TextareaAutosize'

const text1 = 'Lorem ipsum...'
const text2 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...'
const [text, setText] = useState(text1)

const handleChange = () => {
  if (text === text1) {
    setText(text2)
  } else {
    setText(text1)
  }
}

...

<TextareaAutosize value={text} />
<button onClick={handleChange}>change text</button>

...
```

This doesn't work and `TextareaAutosize` just goes into infinite loop and eventually throws error `MUI: Too many re-renders. The layout is unstable. TextareaAutosize limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` and doesn't change it's state.

Also the same is true for [TextField](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/) with `multiline` prop which just uses `TextareaAutosize` as the base and according to the docs can be controlled.

Codepen with `TextareaAutosize`: https://codepen.io/kengho/pen/popGYvx

Codepen with `TextField` : https://codepen.io/kengho/pen/oNpmOZq

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem a while ago and it seems like you can't or should not set a react "state" as a value in `TextareaAutosize`. It somehow will trigger the infinite loop because this is my guess, the `TextareaAutosize` itself is controlling the value already so if you set a react state on it, then there might be two kinds of logic to set the value which caused the problem.

My suggestion:

You can set a `defaultValue={text}` for `TextareaAutosize` instead of `value={text}` if you want to have some initial value for `TextareaAutosize`. (which works for me)

My example:

```
    <TextareaAutosize
      aria-label='TextareaAutosize'
      placeholder='placeholder'
      onChange={event => changeInput(event)}
      defaultValue={anyValue}
    />
```

With the `onChange` event, you can get the value from `TextareaAutosize`, and use `useText` you defined to save the value.